# technique to store contents of multiple large CSV files in memory

Tags: java, local-storage

I'm writing a program that uses large CSV files. These are pretty big files; each one has got around 5,000 lines. Right now I'm just opening them and reading them each time I run the program. However, the content of these CSVs isn't going to change. Do I have to keep opening,reading, and closing the CSV when I run the program or is there a way to store the contents in a more accessible spot?

I'm emailing the program to someone else so I need a way that doesn't use SQL/noSQL databases.

Comment: You may cache contents of each CSV file into some `List<SomeObject> list` once per program run and retrieve data from this collection onwards

Comment: Why don't you convert these files into a SQL (or NoSQL) database?

Comment: Caching is definately needed here but you need to take care of memory as well. I would suggest using SoftReference or specialized libraries like Guava.